# Почему JS не срабатывает при вызове Label?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, update

Суть проблемы, есть `Label` на веб-форме, к которому должно присваиваться значение из БД с помощью метода :

```
protected void UpdateLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = Master.Connect.ORACLE_TESC3();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"select pipe_year||pipe_number||control_number pipenumber, insert_date
                            from insp_scan_history
                            where insp_number = ?
                            and insert_date = (select max(insert_date) from insp_scan_history where insp_number = ?)";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("INSP_NUMBER", WorkplaceId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("INSP_NUMBER1", WorkplaceId);
        using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
                if (rdr.Read())
                    lblLastScanned.Text = "Последняя отсканированная труба: " + rdr["PIPENUMBER"] + " - " + rdr["INSERT_DATE"];
                else
                lblLastScanned.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Значение в `Label` должно обновляться самостоятельно без обновления страницы с интервалом в 2 сек, делаю с помощью JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(() =>
    {
        document.getElementById(prefix + "lblLastScanned").value = document.body.lblLastScanned;
    },
    2000);

}
```

Сам `Label` :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLastScanned" Style="margin-left: 15px" runat="server" OnPreRender="UpdateLabel"/>
```

В итоге в JS функция работает, и она действительно запускается каждые 2 секунды, но не обновляет `Label`, а срабатывает только единожды.

Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в то, что у элемента `body` нет свойства `lblLastScanned` (если только Вы его сами где-то не назначили).

Но предположим, что Вам удалось послать в браузер вместе со страницей строку, которую Вы хотите присвоить `document.getElementById(prefix + "lblLastScanned").value`. (Что такое `prefix`, и что это за элемент? У элемента `label` нет свойства `value`.) Через две секунды эта строка не получит новое значение из базы, а останется такой, какая пришла в браузер со страницей.

Comment: не назначал, а как в таком случае обратиться правильно?

Comment: @Sosiska `ajax` на сервер, который в ответе пренесет вам значение `lblLastScanned`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
получается это будет верно? а уже в файлике который я дополнительно создам будет обращение к `Label`?

Comment: @Sosiska ` url: "test.js"` - что то новенькое ). Я с веб формами не работал никогда...но с увереностью скажу, что вам нужно как то методом `get` по `url` добраться до серверного метода `UpdateLabel`. При чем, `UpdateLabel` должен возвращать (ну например стрингу). И потом на клиенте (в `ajax`) есть свойство `success`, которое принимает функцию с параметром (как раз то, что возвратит метод ваш на сервере). и внутри него вы и впихивайте значение с сервера в вашу лейблу. На счет `dataType: "script"` ... за частую я вижу `xml,json,html`, но не `script`.